# How to create an item list to use multiple times on a Jinja2 template page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, flask, jinja2

I want to create an HTML option list and display it multiple times on the template page. I tried to iterate through the list passed on to the template but this seems only to work once on the page:

```
{% for item in points %}
<option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
{% else %}
No item found..
{% endfor %}
```

The second time I iterate, I get the exception `"No item found.."`. I could not figure out how to create this list once and re-use it with Jinja.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better solution?

The template file:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
{% if session.username %}
    <p>Welcome {{ session.username }}!</p>

    <p>Connect Points:</p>
    <form action="{{ url_for('add_con') }}" method=post>
        First Point<br>
        <input list="first_point" name="first_point">
            <datalist id="first_point">
                {% for item in points %}
                <option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
                {% else %}
                <option><b>No Item found..</b></option>
                {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
            <br />Name:<br />
            <input type="text" name="name">
            Second Point<br>
            <input list="second_point" name="second_point">
            <datalist id="second_point">
                {% for item in points %}
                    <option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option><b>No Item found..</b></option>
                {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Point">
    </form>
{% else %}
<p>You are not logged in!</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you show us the page with both loops?

Comment: Is `points` a list or a generator? If a generator is used up, it won't do anything the second time.

Comment: @PeterWood It should be a generator. I used py2neo's `graph.find()` [link](https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/blob/d33f64cf6bdd1815c131d039be8585e5b7fd48f9/py2neo/core.py) to return a list of nodes saved in `points`.

Comment: You need to turn it into a list: `list(graph.find())`

Comment: Your question could be improved if edited your code to show what `points` is and how it was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Peter Wood in the comments, `points` is a generator:

> You need to turn it into a list: `list(graph.find())`

Thanks!